# MATLAB find the average time using tic toc

Tags: matlab

Construct an experiment to study the performance of the Cramer rule (with two implementations
determinants) in relation to Gauss's algorithm.
In each iteration 10 random arrays A (NxN), and vectors b (Nx1) will be created.
The 10 linear systems will be solved using the Cramer rule ("cramer.m") using
of rec_det (A) and using det (A), and the Gaussian algorithm
(“GaussianElimination.m”), and the time for each technique will be the average of 10 values.
Repeat the above for N = 2 to 10 and make a graph of the average time
in relation to the dimension N.

This is my task. I dont know if the way that I calculate the average time is correct and the graphic is not displayed.

```
  T1=0;
 T2=0;
 T3=0;

for N=2:10

for i=1:10

    A=rand(N,N);
    b=rand(N,1);


    t1=[1,i];
    t2=[1,i];
    t3=[1,i];

    tic;
    crammer(A,b);
    t1(i)=toc;

    tic
    crammer_rec(A,b);
    t2(i)=toc;

    tic
    gaussianElimination(A,b);
    t3(i)=toc;

    T1=T1+t1(i);
    T2=T2+t2(i);
    T3=T3+t3(i);
end
avT1=T1/10;
avT2=T2/10;
avT3=T3/10;

end

plot(2:10 , avT1 , 2:10 , avT2 , 2:10 , avT3);


   function x = cramer(A, b)
    n = length(b);
d = det(A); 
% d = rec_det(A);
x = zeros(n, 1);
for j = 1:n
    x(j) = det([A(:,1:j-1) b A(:,j+1:end)]) / d;
    % x(j) = rec_det([A(:,1:j-1) b A(:,j+1:end)]) / d;
end
 end


function x = cramer(A, b)
n = length(b);
d = rec_det(A);
x = zeros(n, 1);
for j = 1:n
    x(j) = rec_det([A(:,1:j-1) b A(:,j+1:end)]) / d;
end
end

             function deta = rec_det(R)
                  if size(R,1)~=size(R,2)
                     error('Error.Matrix must be square.')
                   else
                     n = size(R,1);
                    if ( n == 2 )
                       deta=(R(1,1)*R(2,2))-(R(1,2)*R(2,1));
                      else
      for i=1:n
          deta_temp=R;
          deta_temp(1,:)=[ ];
          deta_temp(:,i)=[ ];
          if i==1
              deta=(R(1,i)*((-1)^(i+1))*rec_det(deta_temp));
          else
              deta=deta+(R(1,i)*((-1)^(i+1))*rec_det(deta_temp));
          end
      end
  end
end 
 end


    function x = gaussianElimination(A, b)
    [m, n] = size(A);
       if m ~= n
         error('Matrix A must be square!');
     end
n1 = length(b);
if n1 ~= n
    error('Vector b should be equal to the number of rows and columns of A!');
end
Aug = [A b]; % build the augmented matrix
C = zeros(1, n + 1);

% elimination phase
for k = 1:n - 1
    % ensure that the pivoting point is the largest in its column
    [pivot, j] = max(abs(Aug(k:n, k)));
    C = Aug(k, :);
    Aug(k, :) = Aug(j + k - 1, :);
    Aug(j + k - 1, :) = C;
    if Aug(k, k) == 0
        error('Matrix A is singular');
    end
    for i = k + 1:n
        r = Aug(i, k) / Aug(k, k);
        Aug(i, k:n + 1) = Aug(i, k:n + 1) - r * Aug(k, k: n + 1);
    end
end

% back substitution phase
x = zeros(n, 1);
x(n) = Aug(n, n + 1) / Aug(n, n);
for k = n - 1:-1:1
    x(k) = (Aug(k, n + 1) - Aug(k, k + 1:n) * x(k + 1:n)) / Aug(k, k);
end
```

end

Comment: For starters, I'm not entirely sure what you are doing when you instantiate t1-3 each i-th loop to be a 2-element vector then deal only with the i-th element later on, I suspect you need only use `t1=toc` and then `T1 = T1+t1` in each case 1-3.

Beyond that when you then calculate `avT1` and its counterparts, you are overwriting this value each N-th loop which is meaning you end up trying to plot a scalar y-value against a vector of x-values. Maybe you want the N-th index there?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is by creating a 9 * 3 dimensional matrix to contain all the total times, and then take the average at the end.

```
allTimes = zeros(9, 3);

for N=2:10

for ii=1:10

    A=rand(N,N);
    b=rand(N,1);

    tic;
    crammer(A,b);
    temp = toc;
    allTimes(N-1,1) = allTimes(N-1,1) + temp;

    tic
    crammer_rec(A,b);
    temp = toc;
    allTimes(N-1,2) = allTimes(N-1,2) + temp;

    tic
    gaussianElimination(A,b);
    temp = toc;
    allTimes(N-1,3) = allTimes(N-1,3) + temp;

end

end

allTimes = allTimes/10;

figure; plot(2:10, allTimes);
```

You can use this approach because the numbers are quite straightforward and simple. If you had a more complicated setup, the way to store the times/calculate the averages would have to be tweaked.

If you had more functions you could also use function handles and create a third inner loop, but this is a little more advanced.